# symfony Notice: Undefined index: username

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

this code to fetch all user names from my database and print it on a web page but i get this error from this line

```
echo $row['username'];
```

what's the wrong ?

```
<?php

namespace test\stuffBundle\Controller;


use tuto\testBundle\Entity\Users;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {       


        $conn = $this->get('database_connection');

        while ($row = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT username FROM user')) {
            echo $row['username'];
        }
        return $this->render('teststuffBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

my entity user file

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
     /**
     *@var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="MatchP",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $MatchP;
    public function getMatchP()
    {
        return $this->MatchP;
    }

    public function setMatchP($MatchP)
    {
        $this->MatchP = $MatchP;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

my `print_r($row);` output

> ```
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => shar ) [1] => Array ( [username] => koko ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => shar ) [1]
> ```
>
> => Array ( [username] => koko ) )

Comment: `print_r($row);`

Comment: Can you show your `user` Entity code please?

Comment: But the `User` Entity doesn't have a `username`. So your query would be empty. Do you mean a different Entity maybe?

Comment: @AlvinBunk that's fosuserbundle entity i tried to use it with session to edit some  user info and that worked but when i use echo not working

Comment: i tried to use echo $row['MatchP'] and i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's a result set and you need to try like this:

```
$row = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT username FROM user');

foreach( $row as $user){
    echo $user['username'];
}
```

Can you try and see if that works. I'm not certain it will work though.

Comment: i get this eror Call to a member function getUsername() on array

Comment: Can you edit your post and show what `print_r($row);` outputs please?

Comment: i added it to my post